# How to proper mock dependencies injected into another class with python?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I am trying to understand the ways to work with mocks and python.

```py
class B:
    def foo(self, value):
        return value


class A:
    def __init__(self, b: B):
        self._b = b

    def bar(self, value):
        return self._b.foo(value)
```

So a simple dependency, where A depends on B that gets injected via the constructor.

My simple test

```py
class TestX(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch.object(B, 'foo')
    def test_it_should_return_same_value(self, mock_b):
        value = 'X'
        mock_b.return_value = value
        a = A(mock_b)
        self.assertEqual(a.bar(value), value)
        mock_b.assert_called_with(value)
```

Which fails with `AssertionError: <MagicMock name='foo.foo()' id='140112335838224'> != 'X`

Any ideas on why?

Comment: You have mocked `B`, so if you call `B.foo` via `A.bar()`, this also returns a mock (as does each call on the mock by default). Setting the return value of the mock does not set the return value of the mock methods.

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view there's a nice way to work with mocks in Python, using 2 concepts:

1. Python Multiple Inheritance to design your classes
2. Usage of super() and Python's Method Resolution Order (MRO) to inject mocks for classes' dependencies within test code.

Regarding the first point, your classes will look like:

```
class B:
    def foo(self, value):
        return value


class A(B):
    def bar(self, value):
        return super().foo(value)

import unittest

class MockB(B):
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = None

    def foo(self, value):
        return self.value

    def set_b_response(self, value):
        self.value = value

class ASut(A, MockB):
    'Injecting mock in A dependency'

class TestA(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_it_should_return_same_value(self):
        value = 'X'
        a = ASut()
        a.set_b_response(value)        

        self.assertEqual(a.bar(value), value)
```

Seeing the MRO of our SUT classes we can understand why the Multiple Inheritance and the usage of super() allow us to inject mocks in this way.

Resulting MRO for **BotSut**:

```
Help on class ASut in module __main__:

class ASut(A, MockB)
 |  Injecting mock in A dependency
 |  
 |  Method resolution order:
 |      ASut
 |      A
 |      MockB
 |      B
 |      builtins.object
```

For more information:

- https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EiOglTERPEo&t=1351s
- https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TestDouble.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confusing `b` with `b.foo`. You mocked the `b.foo()` method, and then used the mock object as a `B` object parameter for the `A.__init()`. Here's your example with that mistake corrected. I also used different values for the input value and the return value to avoid confusing those.

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch


class B:
    def foo(self, value):
        return value


class A:
    def __init__(self, b: B):
        self._b = b

    def bar(self, value):
        return self._b.foo(value)


class TestX(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch.object(B, 'foo')
    def test_it_should_return_same_value(self, mock_b_foo):
        value_in = 'X'
        value_out = 'Y'
        mock_b_foo.return_value = value_out
        b = B()
        a = A(b)
        self.assertEqual(a.bar(value_in), value_out)
        mock_b_foo.assert_called_with(value_in)
```